# Devise with jquery-mobile, how handle error messages?

Tags: jquery-mobile, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In app with (Gemfile ):

```
gem "devise", ">= 2.1.2"
gem 'rails', '3.2.8' 
gem 'jquery_mobile_rails'
```

Before add jquery-mobile, all works fine, when enter invalidad data i got the page with a error message and log :

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-28 12:01:13 -0500
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"jLtHS2q0wO+tgswm9VM2/EiuTiq7J9Wwp8d65t/RSGE=", "user"=>{"email"=>"", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 0ms
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"jLtHS2q0wO+tgswm9VM2/EiuTiq7J9Wwp8d65t/RSGE=", "user"=>{"email"=>"", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (3.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 29ms (Views: 28.9ms)
```

After add jquery-mobile, when login with correct data works fine, but with invalid data i get 401 and dont redirect noting . In the http response (view with firebug ) show only the message with the error like "invalid email" (not html code nor json) and jquery-mobile show "Error loading page".

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-27 21:32:45 -0500
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"EYx56pui4v6trcuzmXQuhzY2BDHwqrADepKuySx9ub0=", "user"=>{"email"=>"test@test.net", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 0ms
```

I have default devise controller and default views generated.

How handle errors message of devise with jquery mobile ?

Comment: What exactly is the problem here? Devise is supposed to return a `401 Unauthorized` message when the login data is invalid.

Comment: ok, i tested, and you rigth, my problem is after 401, not redirect, with jquery-mobile show "error loading page", without send all html with message error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only not use ajax with jquery-mobile and devise for default.

In `config/initializers/devise.rb`

```
# If http headers should be returned for AJAX requests. True by default.
  config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = false
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to add

```
:html => {:data => {:ajax => 'false'}}
```

to the form in question so jQM doesn't hijack it and turn it into an ajax request.

Please see my full answer for the same question https://stackoverflow.com/a/14595607/64669