# Rails 4 fullcalendar not showing up

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, fullcalendar

I'm trying to add calendar functionality to my rails 4 application. I tried all the steps mentioned below:

1. In application.css:
   *= require.fullcalendar
2. In application.js:
   //= require fullcalendar
3. In events.coffee:
   $('#calendar').fullcalendar()
4. In index.html.erb:

Reference site: http://blog.crowdint.com/2014/02/18/fancy-calendars-for-your-web-application-with-fullcalendar.html

I'm able to create a new event but calendar doesn't show up. Appreciate any help! Using firefox/chrome.

rake routes:

```
              Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                             Controller#Action
              events GET    /events(.:format)                       events#index
                     POST   /events(.:format)                       events#create
           new_event GET    /events/new(.:format)                   events#new
          edit_event GET    /events/:id/edit(.:format)              events#edit
               event GET    /events/:id(.:format)                   events#show
                     PATCH  /events/:id(.:format)                   events#update
                     PUT    /events/:id(.:format)                   events#update
                     DELETE /events/:id(.:format)                   events#destroy
      questionnaires GET    /questionnaires(.:format)               questionnaires#index
                     POST   /questionnaires(.:format)               questionnaires#create
   new_questionnaire GET    /questionnaires/new(.:format)           questionnaires#new
  edit_questionnaire GET    /questionnaires/:id/edit(.:format)      questionnaires#edit
       questionnaire GET    /questionnaires/:id(.:format)           questionnaires#show
                     PATCH  /questionnaires/:id(.:format)           questionnaires#update
                     PUT    /questionnaires/:id(.:format)           questionnaires#update
                     DELETE /questionnaires/:id(.:format)           questionnaires#destroy
  questionnaire_info GET    /questionnaire/info(.:format)           questionnaire#info
        leaving_info GET    /leaving/info(.:format)                 leaving#info

         useful_info GET    /useful/info(.:format)                  useful#info
    new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                devise/sessions#new
        user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                devise/sessions#create
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)               devise/sessions#destroy
       user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)               devise/passwords#create
   new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)           devise/passwords#new
  edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)          devise/passwords#edit
                     PATCH  /users/password(.:format)               devise/passwords#update
                     PUT    /users/password(.:format)               devise/passwords#update

cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                 devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                        devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                   devise/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)                        devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                        devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                        devise/registrations#destroy
              pages_info GET    /pages/info(.:format)                   pages#info
                    root GET    /                                       redirect(301, /ideas)
                   ideas GET    /ideas(.:format)                        ideas#index
                         POST   /ideas(.:format)                        ideas#create
                new_idea GET    /ideas/new(.:format)                    ideas#new
               edit_idea GET    /ideas/:id/edit(.:format)               ideas#edit
                    idea GET    /ideas/:id(.:format)                    ideas#show
                         PATCH  /ideas/:id(.:format)                    ideas#update
                         PUT    /ideas/:id(.:format)                    ideas#update
                         DELETE /ideas/:id(.:format)                    ideas#destroy
```

Comment: So it is hard to tell what is going wrong with your code because we don't see any of your code.  Most of the time, you can tell what is going on from the console or the browser console.  That is the best way to debug your code.  Otherwise, the link below from RailsCasts for implementing a calendar is a great resource.  [RailsCast link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ndBKSjAbemo)

Comment: I started doing this from scratch, created a scaffold for events, added 'gem fullcalendar-rails' to my gemfile and proceeded with the above steps. Everything works fine but calendar doesn't show up

Comment: Are you including jQuery in your application.css file and including it before the `*=require.fullcalendar`?  Or are you including jQuery in your application.html.erb?  It has to be in the right order.

Comment: A good option as well is to check the actual docs.....http://fullcalendar.io/docs/usage/

Comment: Hi, I got the issue, fullcalendar works without devise authentication, but when I add it wont work. How do I fix this, thank you for the patience!

Comment: Could you run rake routes and paste your code in your question?

Comment: Yep pasted the rake routes above

Comment: I know this is from forever ago, but I'm pretty sure this is because fullcalendar is requiring that ajax be enabled and devise doesn't seem to like that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12329406/jquery-mobile-rails-devise-error-loading-page-when-logging-in-with-incorrect-c
I've been trying to apply the advise in the above link in my own app, but so far I've not been able to make it work. If I come up with an actual answer, I'll post it.